# Trying to find a key exists in an unordered map- getting error

Tags: c++, iterator, unordered-map

I am trying to implement the following function to check to see if an unordered_map contains a certain key. Using other answers on here I came up with:

```
bool listcontains(std:: unordered_map<int, bool> mylist, int key){
     return mylist.find(key) != mylist.end();
}
```

The error I am getting is:

```
no operator "!=" matches these operands -- operand types are: 
std::__detail::_Node_iterator<std::pair<const int, bool>, <error-constant>, <error-constant>>!= 
std::__detail::_Node_iterator<std::pair<const int, bool>, <error-constant>, <error-constant>>
```

I am very confused because the operands seem to be the exact same. I am using VS code editor with cpp standard C++17 (according to c_cpp_properties.json) and the g++ version 10.3.0 (according to command window).

Here is my tasks.json file for reference:

```
{
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "type": "cppbuild",
        "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
        "command": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
        "args": [
            "-g",
            "${file}",
            "-o",
            "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
        ],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$gcc"
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        },
        "detail": "compiler: C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe"
    }
]
}
```

Could this perhaps be a compiler issue? I am happy to share more information if needed.

I am new to stack overflow and C++, anything helps. Thanks!

Comment: Passing the argument by value `std:: unordered_map<int, bool> mylist` is very inefficient.

Comment: cannot reproduce: https://godbolt.org/z/f43ETqEzf.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number could this be a compiler issue? I have edited the post to attach my tasks.json for reference

Comment: As an aside, this function seems pointless given the existence of the built-in `find()`. It provides less information. On top of that, C++11 provides `.at()` and C++20 provides `.contains()`.

Comment: I am now using the count() function as such: `if (closed.count(key) == 0)`. I believe this expression will return true if the key is not contained in the map. Thank you all for your input.

Comment: before concluding a compiler bug you should exclude everything else. Please post a [mcve] including includes and all that is needed to reproduce the error